# Filtering data from DF based on multiple conditions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, filter

So I am trying to filter data from my DF based on multiple conditions. I did my research online but I didn't find a working solution yet.

I found 2 methods that I understand but they didn't work either.
And when I filter data using Excel, I can see that there is data based on my conditions, but in Python I am not sure why my code isnt working.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
# need: 
# Value = everything
# Ethnicity = everything

# based on:
# Time = 2004
# Region = All
# Age = All
# Sex = All

# method 1
a = df.loc[(df.Time == "2004") & (df.Region == "All") & (df.Age == "All") & (df.Sex == "All"), ["Ethnicity","Value"]]
print(a)

# method 2
b = np.where((df.Time == "2004") & (df.Region == "All") & (df.Age == "All") & (df.Sex == "All"))
print(df.loc[b])

Output:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Ethnicity, Value]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Measure, Measure_type, Ethnicity, Ethnicity_type, Time, Time_Type, Region, Age, Age_Type, Sex, Value, confidence_interval, Numerator, denominator, samp_size]
Index: []
```

Excel data filtering shows that there is data based on my conditions, but how do I do this in Python?
[See the screenshot from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4XCT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only Dataframe basic filtering syntax like this (You have some errors):

```
df[(df['Time'] == 2004) & (df['Region'] == "All") & (df['Age'] == "All") & (df['Sex'] == "All")]
```

- First in `(df.Time == "2004")`, while importing excel sheet as dataframe, these are automatically casted to correct type here `int` so you need `(df.Time == 2004)`
- Then as you don't need filtering two columns, so omit `["Ethnicity","Value"]`

Answer (score 0):

> a = df[(df.Time == "2004") & (df.Region == "All") & (df.Age == "All") & (df.Sex == "All")]["Ethnicity","Value"]